# How to avoid egg white being cooked in drinks?

Tags: drink, alcohol

So, i love to drink Peruan Pisco sours. You make these with Pisco, lemon juice, sugar and egg's white. You are supposed to shake the drink. However, every time i make this drink, i end up with little pieces of cooked egg in the drink. They are disgusting. How can i avoid this problem, while still conserving the the foam obtained with the eggs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Several suggestions:

- On a fresh egg, remove the chalazae, the ropey bit in the white (it anchors the yolk);
- Use either pasteurized egg whites or powdered egg whites;
- Add ice only after the mixture has become foamy and voluminous;
- Use a finer mesh strainer (if bits are getting through your shaker strainer).

Answer (score 1):

Chicago bartender here. Try adding your egg whites to one half of the shaker and your pisco and citrus to the other. Dry shake first. Then add ice and shake for 20 seconds. Double strain through a mesh strainer.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not familiar with pisco but whatever ingredient is cooking the egg(citrus juice I’d think) needs to be separate when shaking and added afterwords.  It may be already in the glass that you pour the cocktail but finding a bartender that makes them often enough will usually be willing to show you the steps.